# Translation of Ps 16(15), 6 (Vulgata)

Tags: sentence-translation, christianity, vulgata

Verse in question is as follows:

> *Funes ceciderunt mihi in praeclaris; etenim haereditas mea praeclara est mihi.*

It would seem to me that meaning is something like this:

> *Funes*: ropes, bonds, chains
>    *ceciderunt mihi* - ceased, fallen of me
>    *in praeclaris* - in fame (?) - as in: it was bright, glorious (?)
>    *etenim* - because
>    *haereditas mea praeclara est mihi* - I have my bright/great inheritance

Could you please offer a translation of this verse?

Answer (score 5):

Since the biggest difficulty seems to be how to translate *funes*, I thought the following interpretations offer some interesting insights:

> "Well might David say, '*Funes ceciderunt mihi in praeclaris*,' 'The
>   cords' of my tent, my ropes, and the sorrow of my pilgrimage, 'fell to
>   me in a good ground, and I have a goodly heritage.'" (Jeremy
>   Taylor, *The Whole Works of the Rt. Rev. Jeremy Taylor*)

Here's Augustine's take on it:

> "'The lines have fallen to me in glorious places' (ver. 6). The boundaries of
>   my possession have fallen in Your glory as it were by lot, like as God
>   is the possession of the Priests and Levites. Numbers 18:20 'For Mine inheritance is glorious to Me.' 'For Mine inheritance is glorious,' not to all, but to them that see; in whom because I am, 'it is to Me.'" (Augustine, *Commentary on the Psalms*)

Another translation for *funes* that I came across was "lot", so whether its translated as "lines", "cords" or "lot", the idea seems to be a descriptive way of referring to his inheritance or heritage.

Answer (score 4):

*Funis,* literally a rope or chain, seems to be used in its metaphorical meaning of duty, service. *Sequor Funes* and *duco funes* are both conventional phrases for doing ones duty, as if the *funis* was a line of duty. Compare the 'lig-' in 'obligation,' and 'religion,' where 'ligo' is to tie, to bind a person to their duties.

'My duties fell to me amongst the *'praeclari:'*

Take *praeclarus* as "super brilliant." The *praeclari* are 'super brilliant people,' or 'asuper brilliant state of affairs.' And *praeclara mihi* describes *Hereditas,* my Heritage, as 'super brilliant for me, to me,'

Etenim here is epexegetic, rather than a causal explanation. Rather than 'because,' it should be translated as 'And so...' / 'Which means,' or, as my dictionary (Smiths1880) says 'Wherefore...'

Answer (score 4):

> חֲבָלִים נָפְלוּ־לִי בַּנְּעִמִים אַף־נַחֲלָת שָׁפְרָה עָלָי׃
>
> σχοινία ἐπέπεσάν μοι ἐν τοῖς κρατίστοις καὶ γὰρ ἡ κληρονομία μου
>   κρατίστη μοί ἐστιν
>
> Funes ceciderunt mihi in præclaris ; etenim hæreditas mea præclara est
>   mihi.
>
> (KJV)The lines are fallen unto me in pleasant places; yea, I have a
>   goodly heritage.

Psalm 16 (LXX and Vulgata: 15), verse 6.

ḥăḇālīm is literally “ropes”, but it also has a specialised meaning of “ropes used to delimit fields”, and then of “the delimited fields (portions)” themselves. The first half of the verse (“the ropes have fallen for me in excellent places”) is paraphrased more prosaically in the second (“my inheritance is excellent for me”).

The basic meaning of the Hebrew word (“ropes”) is rendered literally by σχοινία and by funes.